# Is ThinkPad X1 Yoga 20FQ 14 Ubuntu compatible?

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I'm looking for a Windows 2 in 1 laptop, and i want to dual boot with Ubuntu studio. Will this work? Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Yoga 20FQ 14 Flip Design 2-in-1 Ultrabook, i7-6500U, 8 GB RAM, 256 GB SSD, 14 FHD (1920x1080) IPS Anti-glare, Back-lit, Windows 10 Pro (20FQ001VUS) (Renewed). Windows 10 will be upgraded to 11 after a while

Comment: ThinkPads are usually pretty good

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Ubuntu is [officially supported by Lenovo](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/lv/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x1-yoga-4th-gen-type-20qf-20qg/solutions/pd031426-linux-for-personal-systems)  on that laptop (if it's the Yoga `20QF` not `20FQ`)